# error while running face recognition program

Tags: face-recognition

I have installed opencv/python 3.7 for windows7. Alsodid a pip install cmake and ensure dlib 19.18.0 is also present.
Pip install of face_recognition proceeded successfully. however when im trying to run a face_recognition python program  itthrows error. I have displayedthe error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\srt1\face_recognition-master\face_recognition-master\tests\test_face_recognition.py", line 17, in 
    from face_recognition import api
  File "H:\Python37\lib\site-packages\face_recognition__init__.py", line 7, in 
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "H:\Python37\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 14, in 
    face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'

Running another python file returns the folliwing error again
RESTART: D:\Users\srt1\face_recognition-master (1)\face_recognition-master\examples\facerec_from_webcam_faster.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\srt1\face_recognition-master (1)\face_recognition-master\examples\facerec_from_webcam_faster.py", line 1, in 
    import face_recognition
  File "H:\Python37\lib\site-packages\face_recognition__init__.py", line 7, in 
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "H:\Python37\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 14, in 
    face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'

> > > 

I feel there is something fundamentally wrong because even if the source python file
contains just one line 
import face_recognition it returns the follwing error while running

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python37/ww.py", line 1, in 
    import face_recognition
  File "H:\Python37\lib\site-packages\face_recognition__init__.py", line 7, in 
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "H:\Python37\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 14, in 
    face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'

Although the pip install face_recognition installs successfully

Please revert.
Thank you

Comment: I believe the problem has something to do with improper installation of dlib. Try reinstalling dlib seperately.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. I had a big problem installing dlib through pip install..it returned error. So ihad todownload tehtar and unzip it and directlycopy it to the python.. site-packages from where i executed the setup.py.Buti wonder whatiswrong with the other errors . The face_recognition module installs successfully so I assumed the program should work..